# See previous commit in Github

Tags: git, github

After searching my `git log` for an old commit, I take its full `hash` paste it into my browser as `https://github.com/my_repo/commit/hash` and so I can see that commit in Github.

Now I want to see the *previous commit* in Github, but I can't find a way to navigate into it.

Is there a way to do this? I wasn't able to find a button/link/anything.

[Here is the link to a commit](https://github.com/asteca/ASteCA/commit/4e5535d3d6b9cb4a29d2805653068e8afe029924) In Github as an example. From that page, how can I see the previous commit?

Comment: Sigh.. What is the point of you leaving a -1 vote if you give no reason why? How is a user supposed to learn from whatever you think s/he did wrong if you simply downvote and say nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the "1 parent" link next to the commit hash.

Comment: Thank you jangler! I totally missed that link and I certainly didn't know it did that.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

in your repo, find these options (most probably it will be on the top, after navigation bar), and click on where it says 3 commits (you may have different numbers) just above the branchmaster dropdown button. (read blue lables in the image above).

Comment: This will show my *all the commits* in my repo, which is not very useful for what I was asking. Thanks anyway!